# how to send output of 'ls-l' to cp command using pipes?

Tags: linux, unix

i want to copy the output of ls -l command into a file say "xyz".
i know i have to take the output of ls -l and then send it to cp command using pipe i.e output of ls-l will be used as an input for cp command

```
$ls-l

-rw-r--r-- 1 1030082 oinstall  167 Mar 27 10:36 \
-rw-r--r-- 1 1030082 oinstall  167 Mar 27 10:36 a1
-rw-r--r-- 1 1030082 oinstall  103 Mar 27 12:40 a2
-rw-r--r-- 1 1030082 oinstall   30 Mar 27 12:43 a3
-rw-r--r-- 1 1030082 oinstall   21 Mar 27 13:47 a4 
drwxr-xr-x 3 1030082 oinstall 4096 Mar 27 16:54 dir1
-rw-r--r-- 1 1030082 oinstall   94 Mar 27 13:53 unix
-rw-r--r-- 1 1030082 oinstall  105 Mar 27 10:33 xyz
```

Comment: The `cp` command is used for copying files. Just use output redirection to put the output in a file.

Comment: you can't use the output of `ls -l` as the input to `cp`, as `cp` will have no idea what to do with the extra info (mode, count,date, etc..)   If you just need to copy all the files in a dir what about `cp * `  and just use standard globs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output to file "test.txt":

```
ls -l > text.txt
```

Sumary of pipes:

- > Save output to a file.
- >> Append output to a file.
- < Read input from a file.
- 2> Redirect error messages.
- | Send the output from one program as input to another program.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to copy the files that are obtained in directory listing into some other directory, then it will be as below

```
for i in $(ls -al  | awk ' { print $9} ' ); do cp -rf $i $destination ; done;
```

If you are simple wanting to copy the output of ls -al into some file, then do

```
ls -al > file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something in file details (time, rights, etc...)

```
cp `ls -l | grep "xxx" | awk '{print $9}'` path_to_your_dest_directory
```

Just replace xxx with what you're looking for and your destination path.